# Symfony 2 and gits : How do i install that vendors library ?? I got errors

Tags: php, symfony, git-svn

I'm trying to set up a Symfony dev platform on webfactionnal.
I'm using Git so when I download S2 I took th "without vendors" version and followed those [instructions.](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/workflow/new_project_git.html#cookbook-managing-vendor-libraries)

So everything went fine until step 8 :`$ php bin/vendors install`

I got several error messages when trying to execute this line on my server :

> Warning: Wrong parameter count for parse_ini_file() in /home/quantum/webapps/quantumnetworks/bin/vendors on line 74
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   /home/quantum/webapps/quantumnetworks/bin/vendors on line 79 sh:
>   ./vendor/bundles/Sensio/Bundle/DistributionBundle/Resources/bin/build_bootstrap.php:
>   No such file or directory
>
> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting
>   T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING or '(' in
>   /home/quantum/webapps/quantumnetworks/app/console on line 13
>
> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting

all the files are originals.

By the way, in the the /config.php I had that error : unable to read logs file, I've put it on 777 on my server and realize that it was named as log instead of logs ... why ?

Thanks !

> T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING or '(' in
>   /home/quantum/webapps/quantumnetworks/app/console on line 13

EDIT : I run php54 command to use php 5.4 as my hosting company advised me. But i still have some errors ,It download evrything, then i have

> Installing/Updating AsseticBundle

and then come the error :

> Receiving objects: 100% (1918/1918), 251.85 KiB | 447 KiB/s, done.
>   Resolving deltas: 100% (1164/1164), done.
>   61c9f363e73b4ecbb72f81eb62675260a1132048 HEAD is now at 41b5913 Merge
>   pull request #27 from stof/disable_profiler
>
> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting
>   T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING or '(' in
>   /home/quantum/webapps/quantumnetworks/vendor/bundles/Sensio/Bundle/DistributionBundle/Resources/bin/build_bootstrap.php
>   on line 35
>
> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting
>   T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING or '(' in
>   /home/quantum/webapps/quantumnetworks/app/console on line 13
>
> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting
>   T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING or '(' in
>   /home/quantum/webapps/quantumnetworks/app/console on line 13

So yeah were making progress, almost done :)

EDIT2 :

I called my host company, they said , when you execute a script in php, even if you type php54, the script itself, if it starts another script, won't call it with the 5.4 version. TO fix that, here are the 4 steps :

```
cd ~/webapps<your application>
ln -s /usr/local/bin/php54 ./php
export PATH=./:$PATH
php54 bin/vendors install
```

need to do all of them

Comment: Can you run `php app/check.php` ? This will do basic checks to now whether your php installation is fine.

Comment: yep php5.3 is used as default when I type in the command line, but I just learned that I can run php54 instead which seems to work (a bit) better

Comment: php 5.3 is supposed to work just fine! Did you run the command I told you to run or not?

Comment: yep, I called my host company, they said , when you execute a script in php, even if you type php54, the script itself, if it starts another script, won't call it with the 5.4 version. TO fix that, here are the 4 steps : See the edit2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not using php 5.3, which is required to run Symfony2.

You can check on the console via

```
php -v
```

which version you currently use.

The `T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING or '(' in [...]` is usually a hint, as php prior to 5.3 does not support Namespaces, which leads to syntax errors in older versions.

Comment: All right, you were right its 5.3 so I called my server hosting company and they told me  to run php54 command ... so it has  installed a bunch of things but i still have some error messages, see the EDIT. thanks